# Change language of menus in an embedded Youtube video?

Tags: iframe, menu, youtube

I'm working on a bilingual website (English/French) and there are some pages with embedded Youtube videos (using the latest iFrame implementation). The English page is fine, however for the French page the drop-down menus in the top right corner of the Youtube video are still in English. I was wondering if it was possible to change the language of the drop-down menus in the Youtube videos? I didn't find any useful [parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) that provided a solution for this. Is this something that might be configurable through the [iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)?

Thanks!